# Passing an array member from a struct causes access reading violation

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, member

I have a `struct` with an array member. I successfully fill this array with values. I Then pass it to a function where i then try to access these same values which results in a access violation. Any ideas?

Here my struct definition:

```
struct testStruct{
 vec3* arr;

  void resizeVerts(int size) {
        arr= new vec3[size];
    }
};
```

I resize and fill the array as follows:

```
testStruct->resizeVerts(vertices.length());
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length(); i++) {
    testStruct->arr[i].x = vertices[i].x;
    testStruct->arr[i].y = vertices[i].y;
    testStruct->arr[i].z = vertices[i].z;
}
```

Now passing it to a function (This is where the error appears) :

```
void ReadFromStruct(struct testStruct){
  vec3 tempArr[1500] = {};
  for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length(); i++) {
    tempArr[i].x=testStruct[i].x;
    tempArr[i].x=testStruct[i].y;
    tempArr[i].x=testStruct[i].z;
  }
```

I tried using vectors but it resulted in vector subscript out of range.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length(); i++) {
            std::vector<vec3> temp;
            temp[i].x = vertices[i].x;
            temp[i].y = vertices[i].y;
            temp[i].z = vertices[i].z;
            testStruct.push_back[temp];
        }
```

## Update

Using vectors and resize instead I have now tried the following:

```
    testStruct->arr.reserve(vertices.length());
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length(); i++) {
    testStruct->arr[i].x = vertices[i].x;
    testStruct->arr[i].y = vertices[i].y;
    testStruct->arr[i].z = vertices[i].z;
}
```

and

```
    testStruct->arr.reserve(vertices.length());
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length(); i++) {
    std::vector<vec3> temp;
    temp.reserve(vertices.length());
    temp[i].x = vertices[i].x;
    temp[i].y = vertices[i].y;
    temp[i].z = vertices[i].z;
    testStruct->arr.push_back(temp[i]);
}
```

Both give me vector subscript out of range crash.

Comment: [mcve] please. Also, why do you use `new`ed arrays when there is `std::vector`?

Comment: Don't make up code while you type the question. You don't even spell the `struct` keyword correctly.

Comment: Please put any code you post through a compiler to make sure it exhibits the problems you are reporting.

Comment: Thank you for having updated your question with code that compiles :-) It's much easier to spot the right issue like that.   It could come from the allocation of `testStruct` (second snippet) or the shallow copy of pointers when passing the struct by value.    But it doesn't change my answer suggesting vectors instead of manually managed memory.

Comment: reserve() is not sufficient:  it doesn't add elements to the vectors, so that the maximul subscribt will still remain 0.  you have to do resize() instead.  And as already said in my answer, you have to move ` std::vector<vec3> temp(vertices.length());`  out of the loop

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
struct testStruct{
   std::vector<vec3> arr;
   void resizeVerts(int size) {
       arr.resize(size);
   }
};
```

This would avoid leaking memory as you could would do if it would work.

Then avoid making the `testStruct` pointer in some parts of the code and use a reference or a local variable instead.

Finally `struct`  is small cap like any C++ keywords.

Comment: I Tried using vectors but then I had problems filling them with correct data and it crashed when running. Check my updated question.

Comment: @Abdominator that's because the initial size of `temp` vector is zero. Change your definition to:  `std::vector<vec3> temp(vertices.length());`  so that the vector immediately has the same size as `vertices`

Comment: @Abdominator, and you must define the vector outside of the loop, otherwise you restart with a new vector at each iteration.  By the way, it would be nice in your question to correct the first snippet because it's not clear how it can compile (is the resizeVerts a member function, or did you redeclare arr as a local variable to avoid a compiler error?) and this tends to irritate the community and cause lots of downvotes

Comment: My bad. I only wanted to show the relevant code so I extracted it, a bit carelessly,  from a larger context.